# kill the nearly duplicate results that came from the 1:n relations in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, linked-data

Is possible to concatenate equivalent results in a SPARQL query? For instance, consider the following RDF data and desired result:

#### knowledge base:

```
@prefix gr:<http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>.

:prod_A gr:color "Red";
        gr:color "Blue".
:prod_B gr:color "Green".
```

#### Ideal Result:

```
| ?prod   | ?color    |
|---------|-----------|
| :prod_A | Red, Blue |
| :prod_B | Green     |
```

The only way through that I see is to use something like this:

```sql
PREFIX gr:<http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>

SELECT ?prod ?color
WHERE {
   ?prod gr:color ?color1.
   OPTIONAL {
       ?prod gr:color ?color2.
       FILTER ( ?color1 != ?color2 )
       bind(concat(?color1,",",?color2) as ?color)
   }
```

but it will work perfectly only if I have exactly 2 matches. Is there a more general and efficient way to do it?

It will be very useful to kill the nearly duplicate results that came from the 1:n relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified to include comments from below:

You can try:

```
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>

SELECT ?prod (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?color; separator=',') as ?colors)
WHERE {
    ?prod gr:color ?color.
}
GROUP BY ?prod
```

example can be found [here](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20gr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A//purl.org/goodrelations/v1%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fprod%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fcolor%3B%20separator%3D%27%2C%27%29%20as%20%3Fcolors%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprod%20gr%3Acolor%20%3Fcolor.%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fprod&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Comment: can I ask you on what resources is based this sparql endpoint?

Comment: It's one of the Virtuoso servers hosted by OpenLink Software to showcase the capabilities of their Virtuoso server software. The endpoint currently seems to say it hosts 62,415,478,623 triples after 120 s timeout (`select count(*) where { [] [] [] }` (it probably hosts more but i didn't want to wait longer)) from several datasets of the LOD Cloud: http://lod-cloud.net/ and "sponged" graphs.

Comment: There's no need for the subquery here.  You can just do `select ?prod (group_concat(distinct ?color; separator=",") as ?colors) { ?prod gr:color ?color } group by ?prod`.

Comment: @ffa Do note that the query here isn't quite legal;  you'll need to fix it to use it with anything except Virtuoso. 1) It needs parentheses around `group_concat(...) as ?colors`.  (Virtuoso doesn't check this, but the spec requires them.) 2) An implicit group for an aggregate can only be used when there are no non-group variables in the projection.  That is, you can't do `select ?prod (group_concat(...) as ?colors)` unless you've got a `group_by` at the outermost level.  (Again, Virtuoso's non-conformance makes it very easy to introduce bugs that will be hidden until you try another endpoint.)

Comment: @ffa You can see a shortened and legal version in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/aNrZsu0S).

Comment: thank you very much @Joshua, indeed I was wandering why it doesn't work with Stardog

Comment: sorry, i seem to work with virtuoso too often ;)

Comment: updated the answer. i hope it's yet another weird coincidence that the lod.openlinksw.com endpoint started responding with errors just after i ran the new query against it...